# Keep repeating alert from navigator.geolocation until acknowledged

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm checking the `navigator.geolocation`.

If in case the user denies the permission they will be redirected to another page. That's fine, but I want that when they are redirected to another page; another alert appears for them to allow location.

How do I make another alert appear for them to allow it; in case they refuse?

[image: browser alert]

I want to create an alert loop for the user to allow location, until they accept.

Comment: If they refuse, then stop asking them and present content on the page that says, "Please allow location services...". Done.

Comment: I'm going to have to do this there's an old topic here on overflow that wasn't answered either, but I wanted to present the permission alert again

Comment: Probably impossibly impossible. Browsers just stop asking if  it's once blocked